# after reading bytes from a file in binary mode, how to find the current position

Tags: python-3.x, file, binary

```
f = open(file_name, "rb")
header = numpy.frombuffer(f.read(4*4), dtype="int32")
```

How do I know the actual position inside the binary data, by code, I know it is 16, but what if is a variable number?

Answer (score 1):

`f.tell()` returns an integer giving the file object’s current position in the file represented as number of bytes from the beginning of the file when in binary mode and an opaque number when in text mode.